# How to correctly add bibtex bibliography with latex?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have added bibliography in my latex file like so :

```
...to the literature \cite{ahu61}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

and my `bibliography.bib` looks like this :

```
@article{ahu61,
       author={Arrow, Kenneth J. and Leonid Hurwicz and Hirofumi Uzawa},
       title={Constraint qualifications in maximization problems},
       journal={Naval Research Logistics Quarterly},
       volume={8},
       year = 1961,
       pages = {175-191}
     }
```

If i keep the citation I get

```
Texification succeeded: no errors!

However, there were warnings in your LaTeX source

./main.tex:231: LaTeX Warning: Citation `ahu61' on page 4 undefined on input line 231.
./main.tex: LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

and no bibliography.

If I remove it I get no warnings but no bibliography either.

Comment: Do you get a BibTeX log (`.blg`) file? If so, what does it say?

Comment: @JosephWright I have `main.blg` with following contents : http://paste.ubuntu.com/6656249/  `I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux`

Comment: That suggests you've got no `\bibliographystyle` line in your LaTeX source: you have to have one

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks! I have added one and now it works:) Here is a short list of available bibliography styles http://www.reed.edu/cis/help/latex/bibtexstyles.html. You can submit an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A minimal LaTeX file using 'standard' has to have a `\bibliographystyle` line in addition to the `\bibliography` line and one or more citations (`\cite`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}
...to the literature \cite{ahu61}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

There are many existing styles: the correct choice will depend on your situation.